# Uncaught ReferenceError: var is not defined & cannot read property

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I try to recover dynamycally the width and height of an iframe at the load of its integration, but I have errors.

**HTML**

An exemple of an iframe, that I try to recuperate width and height.

```
<iframe src="" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" width="640" height="360"></iframe>
```

**jQuery**

```
var frameEl = window.frameElement;
var widthIframe = frameEl.width;
var heightIframe = frameEl.height;
```

For this code, I have.

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'width' of null
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
>       at HTMLDocument.

After I tried to add a ready handler, and I have.

```
$(function()
{
    $.extend(window, {
         frameEl: window.frameElement,
         widthIframe: frameEl.width,
         heightIframe: frameEl.height,
    });
});
```

> jQuery.Deferred exception: heightIframe is not defined ReferenceError:
>   heightIframe is not defined
>       at HTMLDocument.

And

> jQuery.Deferred exception: frameEl is not defined ReferenceError:
>   frameEl is not defined
>       at HTMLDocument.

Thank's for your help to tell me what it's wrong.

Comment: Is this code in the `iframe`, or in the document *containing* the `iframe`? If the latter, that's the problem. You use `window.frameElement` from the document *in the frame* to access the element that contains it.

Comment: What is purpose of using `$.extend()`?

Comment: The jQuery code is in an document and in an other I call the html code.

Comment: I tested $.extend() like in an other exemple which find in this forum. The error was modify after add this, so I thought that maybe can be the solution with the good syntax.

Comment: Are you trying to set the `widthIframe`, `heightIframe` as global properties? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, I never try to set as this variable as global properties.
I'm try to recover values of the iframe when it was integrated (in my exemple 640 & 360) to adapt to content in the iframe.
So I iniatialized two variables to recover values and use them after to adapt a player.
To give for the player the same width and height of the iframe, I did 
`$(".mediaplayer").css("height", heightIframe + "px");`
`$(".mediaplayer").css("width", widthIframe + "px");`

Comment: @Nador: You don't 'call' HTML. Again: Is this code supposed to run in a document **in** the `iframe` and access the `iframe` element it's in? Or is it in the document **containing** the `iframe` and supposed to access the `iframe` element in the document?